# validate variable with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

it is a code to submit several grades in one submission
this is the javascript code fore validation

```
function validateForm() {
    var x='<?php echo ($grade);?>';

    if (x>100) {
        alert("Invalid Data Entry");
        return false;
    }
```

it is not accessing the variable grade in the third echo down

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="insertgradeac.php"onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<?php
    $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($database);

    $query_fetch5 = "SELECT ass_class FROM assess WHERE ass_ID LIKE '$id'";
    $result_fetch5 = mysql_query($query_fetch5);
    $row5 = mysql_fetch_row($result_fetch5);
    $row5_0 = $row5[0];

    $query_fetch = "SELECT st_ID, st_name FROM student WHERE class_ID LIKE '$row5_0'";
    $result_fetch = mysql_query($query_fetch);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result_fetch)) {
        echo "<tr>\n";

        echo "<td>$row[0]<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"stt_ID[]\" value=\"$row[0]\" /></td>\n";
        echo "<td>$row[1]<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"student[]\" value=\"$row[1]\" /></td>\n";
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"grade[]\" /></td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }


    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That JS function will run in the browser, but it is trying to access a PHP variable that won't be set until after the form is submitted to the web server.

Comment: The javascript you pasted is invalid. Firstly in the validateForm() function you are essentially just assigning `x` to a string and then checking if it is greater than 100. Secondly, the `?>` at the end of your code is a PHP closing tag and does not belong in a JavaScript script. I think you are misunderstanding how PHP and JavaScript interacts given the first runs on the Server and the latter on the Client Browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JS function will run in the browser, but it is trying to access a PHP variable that won't be set until after the form is submitted to the web server.

Try this instead:

```
function validateForm()
{
  var grades = document.getElementsByName("grade[]");
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
     if (Number(grades[i].value) > 100) {
        alert("Grades cannot be more than 100.");
        return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

I've used the [`getElementsByName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) to get a list of all of the `grades[]` elements, then I loop over them testing their values and displaying the alert if the value is no good.

You don't actually say how you call `validateForm()`, but I assume you do so from the submit event of your form.

Note that you should also add some code to confirm that the entered value is actually a number, and you need to do the same validation in your server-side PHP code in case a user has JS turned off (or uses browser dev tools to bypass your validation).

Answer (score 0):

In the first block I notice:

You are setting x as a string... and later comparing it as a number/int. Remove the apostrophes when setting x.

In the second block I notice you are usong $id in your query without first setting (and sanitizing) it.

Comment: it did not solve the problem i think the problem is in the variable grade to access it as an input of the form or a php variable

Comment: When the php is processed to html/javascript and sent to your server, have you done 'view source' in the browser to see if the javascript is as expected? Please show us the html that goes to the browser

Comment: i just didn't write it here anyway  there isn't problem in setting the grades everything is working perfect just the validation is not working

Comment: Still I would like to see your compiled html/javascript received by the browser. Don't forget... All php is first processed on the server. Then sent to the browser. Then the browser processes the Javascript. The browser wont do any php work anymore